# Multi-dependent ComboBox issues

Tags: vba, combobox, solidworks

Im attempting to create a bolt generator in Solidworks using an API. One of the userforms I have made builds a socket head bolt I.A.W ISO 4762. At the moment I have 3 comboboxes; A nominal bolt diameter selection, a bolt length selection and a thread length selection.

The value displayed in the thread length selection are dependent on the value selected in the bolt section and the value displayed in the bolt section are dependent on the nominal bolt diameter. This makes the thread selection dependent on both values of the prior comboboxes. The code I have written is below

```
Private Sub SSocketl_Change()

SSockett.Clear 'Clears the contents of SSockett whenever SSocketl changes selection

If SSocketd.Text = "M2.5" Then             'Nominal Bolt Diameter
        If SSocketl.Value = "25" Then      'Bolt Length
                SSockett.AddItem ("17")    'Thread Length

End If

        If SSocketl.Value <= "20" Then     'Bolt Length
               SSockett.AddItem ("Full")   'Thread Length
    End If
End If
```

If the user picks a diameter of M2.5 and a bolt length of 25mm the thread length must be '17mm' (This works). If the bolt length is less than 20mm the thread length must be 'Full' (This also works) unless the bolt length is less than 10mm, in this case the thread length box remains empty when it should say 'Full'.

Can anyone offer any advice or a solution to this problem? It seems to defy logic

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Fairly certain you actually mean `CLng(SSocketl.Value) <= 20` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings and not numbers ("20" instead of 20 ).
When comparing strings; VBA uses the sort order to determine which one is bigger. That is why if you test "9" < "20" it will evaluate to False.
See Link [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators) for more details.

If your stored values are numeric, then you can compare numbers by removing the double quotes:

```
If SSocketl.Value <= 20 Then
```

If your stored values are strings, then you can use Val() to interpret the string as a number and so be able to compare numbers:

```
If Val(SSocketl.Value) <= 20 Then
```

Comment: That's worked great, thank you. In my previous comboboxes where im declaring what values can be used I have typed     SSocketl.AddItem ("3"). So I take these out of the " " too if theyre numeric?